# Ошибка "Invalid floating point operation"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var y, yInDegree, EPS, diff, x, yMinus1 : Extended;
    i, n : Cardinal;
begin
  x := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  n := StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
  EPS := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  i := 1;
  y := 1.0;
  yInDegree := 1.0;
  while (diff > EPS) do
    begin
    yMinus1 := y;
    y := ((1/n) * ((n-1) * y + (x/yInDegree)));  // <<<-- Ошибка тут
    yInDegree := exp(n*ln(y));
    diff := y - yMinus1;
    inc(i);
    end;
  Label5.Caption := IntToStr(i);
end;
```

Текст ошибки:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInvalidOp with message 'Invalid floating point operation'

Ошибка вылетает на строке `y := ((1/n) * ((n-1) * y + (x/yInDegree)));`.

Comment: и комментарий этот точно не нжуен

Comment: Не компилируется или не работает? Какой текст ошибки? На какой строке?

Comment: ошибка вылетает на строке y := ((1/n) * ((n-1) * y + (x/yInDegree)));
Текст ошибки : Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInvalidOp with message 'Invalid floating point operation'

Comment: n (оно же Edit3.text) точно не ноль?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Либо `n`, либо, что более вероятно `yInDegree` на очередной итерации принимают значения около нуля.

Модифицируйте код

```
try
   y := ((1/n) * ((n-1) * y + (x/yInDegree)));
except
  ShowMessageFmt('n: %f, y: %f, yInDegree: %d', [n, y, yInDegree]);
end;
```

и посмотрите на получаемые значения